# Event listener clearing console.log

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I am trying to get along with creating chrome extension.

Something weird is happening, On clicking on my input submit, it clears my console log (more like, it refreshed my index page).

Here is my app.js page

```
var color = document.getElementById('fontColor');
  var colors;


function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener){
  var events = eventNames.split(' ');
   for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
      element.addEventListener(events[i], listener);
    }
}

addListenerMulti(color, 'change paste color', function(){
colors = document.getElementById("fontColor").value;
console.log(colors);
});

document.getElementById('btn-change').addEventListener("click", function() {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {todo: "changeColor", clickedColor: colors})
});
```

and Index.html file.

```
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title> Tinder Auto Swipe </title>
</head>

  <body>
    <h2> Select the color </h2>
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="jscolor" id="fontColor" value="#AB2567">
      <input type="submit" value="Change" id="btn-change">
    </form>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src = "scripts/jscolor.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="app.js">
  </script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with fixing this? Also, If you need additional details then do let me know.

Comment: What's your expected behavior when submit button is clicked?

Comment: @abdul-wahab Okay: So i updated my js file a bit in click event handler (it still doesn't work).

My goal is to change the color of an element on the page. <br>

But, For this question, I am trying to understand why is it clearing my console.log.  

If in case this helps, here is my files on github
https://github.com/irohitb/colorchange

Comment: It is clearing you console because when you click "Change", it submits and navigates the form to the same address, because it's input type is `submit`.

Comment: You can use `Preserve log` in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearing the console because when you click "Change" button, it submits and navigates the form to the same address, because it's input type is submit (`type="submit"`).

To prevent form from submitting, either change input type to button:

```
<input type="button" value="Change" id="btn-change">
```

Or don't let form from submitting by using:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Or more safely:

```
 <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return false;">
```

**Or by configuring *Console***

If form submission is what you desire, you can prevent *chrome console* from clearing itself when a navigation occurrs, by "checking" **Preserve Log** options, see below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your form dosen't have any handle. So in default behaviour it will re-load the current page. you can avoid it by adding

```
<form onsubmit='return false;'></form>
```

it will avoid refresh the page Or you can call your own custom function and add

```
return false;
```

in it.